# Resizing div using jquery causes child image to lose aspect ratio

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design, image-scaling, aspect-ratio

I have some code in place that resizes a div containing my logo to match the current height of a seperate `<ul>`. In the CSS, the logo `<img>` has the following attributes:

```
.logo img {
    height:100%;
    width:auto;
}
```

Meaning that the image will be as tall as the div it is contained in, and the auto height should preserve the aspect ratio, however in some circumstances the image is stretching when it is resized. A basic version of my current code can be found here: http://flatpackstudios.com/2014%20Site/index.html

The issue seems to arise when you make your browser window small enough that the black menu wraps down to 2 or 3 lines of text, then you expand the window horizontally so it reverts back to one line (but keeping the window short enough so that you can scroll vertically). When you then scroll down the `width:auto` on the `.logo img` doesn't seem to kick in, and the image stretches.

Here is are some screenshots of the problem:

[image: jquery image scaling issue]

And finally, the CSS and Jquery for the parent box itself:

CSS:

```
.logo {
    position:fixed;
    top:17px;
    left:20px;
    z-index:100;
    text-align:right;   
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
            if($(this).scrollTop() > stickerTop && $(window).width() > 480) {
                $("#sticker").css({position:'fixed',top:'0px'});
                $(".logo").css({top:'3px', zIndex:'1000', width:'122px', height: stickerHeight - 6, cursor:'pointer'});
                $('#page').css('padding-top',stickerHeight + 20);
            }

            else {
                $("#sticker").css({position:'relative'});
                $(".logo").css({width: 'auto', zIndex:'auto', height: 'auto', top: '17px', cursor:'default'});
                $('#page').css('padding-top','20px');
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try:

```
.logo img {
   max-height: 100%;
   max-width: 100%;
}
```

and some other dimensions for div.logo to fit your goal.